# Transform the Random time intervals to 30 mins Structured interval

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataFrame where some tasks happened time period

```
                    Date       Start Time              End Time
0     2016-01-01 0:00:00   2016-01-01 0:10:00   2016-01-01 0:25:00
1     2016-01-01 0:00:00   2016-01-01 1:17:00   2016-01-01 1:31:00
2     2016-01-02 0:00:00   2016-01-02 0:30:00   2016-01-02 0:32:00
...                  ...                  ...                  ...
```

Convert this df to 30 mins interval
Expected outcome

```
                    Date       Hours              
1     2016-01-01 0:30:00        0:15
2     2016-01-01 1:00:00        0:00
3     2016-01-01 1:30:00        0:13
4     2016-01-01 2:00:00        0:01
5     2016-01-01 2:30:00        0:00
6     2016-01-01 3:00:00        0:00
...                  ...            
47     2016-01-01 23:30:00        0:00
48     2016-01-02 23:59:59        0:00
49     2016-01-02 00:30:00        0:00
50     2016-01-02 01:00:00        0:02
...                  ...
```

I was trying to do with for loop which was getting tedious. Any simple way to do in pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can discard the `Date` column, get the time difference between start and end, `groupby` 30 minutes and `agg` on `first` (assuming you always have one entry only per 30 minutes slot):

```
print (df.assign(Diff=df["End Time"]-df["Start Time"])
         .groupby(pd.Grouper(key="Start Time", freq="30T"))
         .agg({"Diff": "first"})
         .fillna(pd.Timedelta(seconds=0)))

                               Diff
Start Time                         
2016-01-01 00:00:00 0 days 00:15:00
2016-01-01 00:30:00 0 days 00:00:00
2016-01-01 01:00:00 0 days 00:14:00
2016-01-01 01:30:00 0 days 00:00:00
2016-01-01 02:00:00 0 days 00:00:00
2016-01-01 02:30:00 0 days 00:00:00
...
2016-01-02 00:30:00 0 days 00:02:00
```

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to create a series with 0 and `DatetimeIndex` per minutes between `min` start time and `max` end time. Then add 1 where Start Time and subtract 1 where End Time. You can then use `cumsum` to count the values between Start and End, `resample.sum` per 30 minutes and `reset_index`. The last line of code is to get the proper format in the Hours column.

```
#create a series of 0 with a datetime index 
res = pd.Series(data=0, 
                index= pd.DatetimeIndex(pd.date_range(df['Start Time'].min(), 
                                                      df['End Time'].max(), 
                                                      freq='T'), 
                                        name='Dates'),
                name='Hours')

# add 1 o the start time and remove 1 to the end start
res[df['Start Time']] += 1
res[df['End Time']] -= 1

# cumsum to get the right value for each minute then resample per 30 minutes
res = (res.cumsum()
          .resample('30T', label='right').sum()
          .reset_index('Dates')
      )

# change the format of the Hours column, honestly not necessary
res['Hours'] =  pd.to_datetime(res['Hours'], format='%M').dt.strftime('%H:%M') # or .dt.time

print(res)
                 Dates  Hours
0  2016-01-01 00:30:00  00:15
1  2016-01-01 01:00:00  00:00
2  2016-01-01 01:30:00  00:13
3  2016-01-01 02:00:00  00:01
4  2016-01-01 02:30:00  00:00
5  2016-01-01 03:00:00  00:00
...
48 2016-01-02 00:30:00  00:00
49 2016-01-02 01:00:00  00:02
```